# Saving JSON file to server from concatenated string in Javascript/AJAX

Tags: jquery, ajax, json

I am generating a concatenated string in Javascript:

```
var result = '';
for (i = 0; i < j.result.length; i++) {
// bunch of string formatting code here
result += stringAsWeGo;
}
```

This "result" string is a string object formatted to look like JSON...I want to save this string as a .json file on my server.  So I am using AJAX and PHP like this:

```
var obj = JSON.parse(result);

$.ajax({
        url: 'json.php',
        data: obj,
        dataType: "json",
        type: "POST"    
       });
```

Where my json.php file looks like this:

```
<?php

$json = $_POST['json'];
$file = fopen('jsonfile.json', 'w+');
fwrite($file, $json);
fclose($file);

?>
```

But nothing is writing to the server. The existing blank jsonfile.json file is empty with no json in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you don't have a param named `json` so try

```
//var obj = JSON.parse(result);

$.ajax({
    url: 'json.php',
    data: {
        json: result
    },
    dataType: "json",
    type: "POST"
});
```

Note: Don't create a json object using string concatenation. You can create an object then use `JSON.stringify()` to sent the value to server as a param value.

```
var obj = {};

//do some processing here which adds some properties to obj like
obj.name = 'x';
obj.id = 4

$.ajax({
    url: 'json.php',
    data: {
        json: JSON.stringify(obj)
    },
    dataType: "json",
    type: "POST"
});
```

Comment: almost perfect...but here's the weird thing. If I document.write the output after JSON.stringify and copy/paste that output from the browser into a JSON validator its perfect...but if I take the JSON that is saved in the file on the server it does not pass validation. It looks identical.  Could it have to do with come kind of encoding not happening in the php file?

Comment: @Cybernetic could be... can you post a sample